# Unable to use "node" command via SSH

Tags: node.js, ssh

I have set up a Ubuntu 14.04 server in Virtual box and installed with `node.js`.

I could run the command "`node server.js`" normally in the virtual box.

However, when I use my windows 10 command prompt to connect the server by "ssh user@192.168.x.x" and run "`node server.js`", it shows up:

The program 'node' can be found in the following packages:
* node
* nodejs-legacy
Ask your administrator to install one of them

What should I do?

Comment: set path for node on ubuntu system variables that will help to recognize globally . Concept missing i think is Globally Not being recognized in your OS .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely due to the way you installed node, it's not in your [PATH](http://www.linfo.org/path_env_var.html).
This can be due to logging in with a different user than the one you used to install ( that has different path settings ), or it can be due to how the shell is configured w.r.t. [login and non-login](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/170493/login-non-login-and-interactive-non-interactive-shells) shells which in essence govern what configuration scripts are sourced and thus what is the value of `$PATH`.

You could try to run running with:

```
echo $PATH
```

Both directly and trough ssh to compare the configuration.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I compared the results of "echo $PATH" in virtual box and windows, and I could see that the path of nodejs is missing in windows. So how could I add the path to it? Sorry that I am a beginner of Linux.

Comment: You can use (this answer)[https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path] as a guideline. In essence it's `export PATH=$PATH:/the/missing/dir/here` if you run this `node` will start working, but only until your next session, you have to add it to the shell's initialization scripts to make it permanent. It's generally easier to install node [using the package manager](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions).

Answer (score -2):

Try the following:

```
nodejs server.js
```